# Pushing git changes from parent directory?

Tags: git

I had a quick question on git. Say I create a git remote in the folder `dist`, which has a parent directory of `app` (i.e. the path of `dist` is `app\dist`). If there are any changes in the files of the `app` directory, will the git remote recognize these changes?

And if not, how would I ensure that the git remote does recognize changes from a parent directory?

Comment: You'd need to `git init` the `dist` folder so it is a standalone Git repository probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git is only interested in files which are in `.git`'s folder and this folder's children. If you want to track/index files in parent-directory, you need to initialize git there.

You could then ignore all directories you do not want to track. E.g. `app/dist` would be tracked, but adding `dontwantthisfolder`to `.gitignore` will not track it.

`git remote`, btw, and I don't know, if you mean this, shows actually `remote` repositories, like `origin`, for example.